# How to avoid warning: Outer scope values like 'userDTO' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component

Tags: reactjs, redux, use-effect

`getTransactions` method call need to be called only if **user is logged in**, but the info about the user will not be visible.

What can I do to force a reload when on other component user log in, and also, how to get rid of the warning?

```
Outer scope values like 'userDTO' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component
```

The info comes from Redux.

```js
import { getTransactions } from '../../tikexModule/MyTicket'
import { userDTO } from '../../tikexModule/slices/tikexAPI'
interface MyTicketListProps {}

export default function MyTicketList(props: MyTicketListProps) {
    const [transactionsOrPassTickets, setTransactionsOrPassTickets] =
        useState<TransactionOrPassTicket[]>()
    useEffect(() => {
        if (userDTO()) {
            getTransactions(setTransactionsOrPassTickets, window.location.search)
        }
    }, [userDTO])
```

userDTO is in `slice.ts`

```js
export const userDTOS = createSelector(
    [authnResS],
    (authnRes?: AuthnRes) => authnRes?.data
)
export const userDTO = () => useAppSelector(userDTOS)
```

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies used for `useEffect` should be defined in inner scope, since you are importing `useDto` it is from outer scope so it wont be a dependency. You either remove it

Or you create a new variable in inner scope and assign it to `userDto` like this

```
export default function MyTicketList(props: MyTicketListProps) {
    const _userDto=userDto
    const [transactionsOrPassTickets, setTransactionsOrPassTickets] =
        useState<TransactionOrPassTicket[]>()
    useEffect(() => {
        if (_userDTO()) {
            getTransactions(setTransactionsOrPassTickets, window.location.search)
        }
    }, [_userDTO])
```

Answer (score -1):

it's unclear to me what you mean by userDTO, could you elaborate ?

if it's a store value i'd suggest you use [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) hook to automatically render when it changes.